# How to pass row information from a table to another table LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, table, component

I'm trying to pass the information of my table after click on add button, the component should pass the value of each cell in the selected row to a child component that is a table true. i'm actually using message channel to fix this but it is no working.

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="New Product Shipment">
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="end">
        <lightning-layout-item size="8" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Search Products" value={productName} onchange={handelproductName}
                placeholder="Product Name">
            </lightning-input>

        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="3" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-button label="Search" variant="brand" onclick={getProducts}>
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>

    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="end">


        <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">

            <!--tabla con productos-->
            <template if:true={showTables}>

                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Products </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Quantity</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Add</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <template for:each={products} for:item="product" for:index="index">
                            <tr  key={product.Id}>
                                <td>
                                    {product.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-m-bottom_large">
                                        <lightning-input type="Number" name={index} onchange={handleChange}>
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    
                                    <div>
                                        <lightning-button  data-id={product.Id} key={product.Id} variant="brand-outline" label="Add"
                                            title="Primary action with lighter look" onclick={handleClick}
                                            name={index} disabled={Buttontrue}
                                            class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <br />
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <div class="slds-p-right_xx-small">

                        <lightning-button label="Prev" disabled={isPrev} onclick={handlePrev} variant="brand"
                            icon-name="utility:back" name="prev"></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                    <span class="slds-badge slds-badge_lightest">
                        {recordStart}-{recordEnd} of {totalRecords} | Page {pageNumber} of {totalPages}
                    </span>
                    <div class="slds-p-left_xx-small">
                        <lightning-button label="Next" disabled={isNext} onclick={handleNext} variant="brand"
                            icon-name="utility:forward" icon-position="right" name="next"></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:true={isDisplay}>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <br />
                    No records found
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>

        <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">
            <template if:true={showTables}>

                <c-child-Table-Comp productshipments={rowData}></c-child-Table-Comp>

            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>


    </lightning-layout>

</lightning-card>
```

parent js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import SearchProducts from '@salesforce/apex/SearchController.SearchProducts';
import SelectedProducts from '@salesforce/messageChannel/SelectedProducts__c';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';


export default class CreateProductShipment extends LightningElement {
    productShipment; 
        

    @api recordId;
     quantity ;
    @track pageSize = 5;
    @track pageNumber = 1;
    @track totalRecords = 0;
    @track totalPages = 0;
    @track recordEnd = 0;
    @track recordStart = 0;
    @track isPrev = true;
    @track isNext = true;
    @track products = [];
    @track errors = null;
    @track isDisplay = false;
    @track value = 0;
    array = [];
    @track product;
    @track showChild = false;
    @track showTables = false;
    lickedButtonLabel;
    @track Buttontrue=true;
    @track test = false;
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    visibleProducts;
    

    handelproductName(event){
        this.productName = event.target.value;
        
     }   

    getProducts(){
        SearchProducts({
            prodName: this.productName, 
            pageSize : this.pageSize, 
            pageNumber : this.pageNumber
        })
        .then(result => {
            if(result){
                var resultData = JSON.parse(result);
                this.products = resultData.products;
                this.pageNumber = resultData.pageNumber;
                this.totalRecords = resultData.totalRecords;
                this.recordStart = resultData.recordStart;
                this.recordEnd = resultData.recordEnd;
                this.totalPages = Math.ceil(resultData.totalRecords / this.pageSize);
                this.isNext = (this.pageNumber == this.totalPages || this.totalPages == 0);
                this.isPrev = (this.pageNumber == 1 || this.totalRecords < this.pageSize);
                if(this.products){
                    if(this.products.length == 0){
                        this.isDisplay = true;
                        this.showTables = false;
                    }else{
                        this.isDisplay = false;
                        this.showTables = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
           
            this.errors = error;
            });

            
    }
    handleNext(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber+1;
        this.getProducts();
    }
 

    handlePrev(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber-1;
        this.getProducts();
    }
    
    handleChange(event){
        
        this.value = event.target.value
        if(this.value > 0){
            this.Buttontrue=false;
            
        }
    }
    
        
    pdateContactHandler(event){
        this.visibleProducts=[...event.detail.records]
    }
    handleClick(event) {

        const itemIndex = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
        const rowData = this.visibleProducts[itemIndex];
        publish(this.messageContext, SelectedProducts, rowData);

        console.log('row'+rowData);
        console.log(rowData.Name);
    }
```

child html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">Products </div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">Quantity</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">Opportunity</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={productShipments} for:item="productshipment">
                <tr key={productshipment.id}>
                    <td>
                        {productshipment.product}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {productshipment.quantity}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {productshipment.opportunity}
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
     
</lightning-card>  
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" type="submit" class="slds-m-right_x-small">
</lightning-button>
</template>
```

child js

```
import { LightningElement, api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe,unsubscribe,APPLICATION_SCOPE,MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import selectedProducts  from "@salesforce/messageChannel/selectedProducts__c";





export default class ChildTableComp extends LightningElement {
    @api productShipments;
    subscription = null;
    
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

    subscribeToMessageChannel() {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                selectedProducts,
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );
        }
    }

    unsubscribeToMessageChannel() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription);
        this.subscription = null;
    }

    handleMessage(message) {
        this.productShipments = message.Name;

        console.log('prodd' + this.productShipments)
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Instead of a code dump and _it is no working._ including a [*Minimal*, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing productshipments in a wrong way each capital letter must be separated by hyphen (-) also for parent to child communication use api method. You can see all recipes [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc)

```
<lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">
    <template if:true={showTables}>
        <c-child-Table-Comp product-shipments={rowData}></c-child-Table-Comp>
    </template>
</lightning-layout-item>
```